# single row selection in my table n reflect it back

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4, uistoryboard

i wanna do a single selection in my table view here is my code any help would be appreciated thanks

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    // Selection logic will go here to place a tick mark next to the selected country

```
currentCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
NSInteger catIndex = [countryList indexOfObject:self.currentCategory];
if (catIndex == indexPath.row) {
    return;
}
NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:catIndex inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.currentCategory = [countryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];
if (oldCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

NSLog(@"the selected cell is %@",newCell);


 }
```

Comment: hey got the answer...current category is a string not a array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

current category is a string not a array here is the correct code for it

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

NSInteger genderIndex = [genderList indexOfObject:self.selectedGender];

if (genderIndex == indexPath.row) {
    return;
}

NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:genderIndex inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.selectedGender = [genderList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];
if (oldCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

NSLog(@"the selected cell is %@",selectedGender);
```

}